# Arduino in the same powerline as a 12V regulator reboots when turning on the regulator

Tags: arduino, current, dc-dc-converter

I'm building an small project where an Arduino is driving a 12V voltage regulator for turning on some devices. The devices consumption will never go up over one ampere.

The Arduino is an MKRZERO.  It is powered by a 3.7V Li-ion battery. The voltage regulator relies on the MAX1771 IC and is also powered by the same battery as the Arduino.

The schematic looks like this:

[image]

The tag "EN_12VDD" is connected to a digital pin of the Arduino which is powered also by the battery with the special connector that the MKRZERO comes with.

The idea is to turn on or off the +12V power line by issuing a `digitalWrite()` on the digital pin.

This circuit works as intended, but at certain times, when turning on the +12V power line with load will cause the arduino to reboot. Looking with the oscilloscope the +BATT power line I can see draw current peaks when turning on the +12V power line. Incrementing the C4 capacitor size reduces the peaks a little bit, but the Arduino is still rebooting.

I though that may be adding a resistor between the +BATT connector and the capacitor C4, might help reducing the current draw, but I'm not sure how can I solve this problem without isolating the powerlines of the regulator and the Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you could look at.
The most likely is a poor ground connection between those shown in your circuit and that of the Arduino. Make sure that sudden changes in current draw don't cause the ground of the PSU to jump with respect to the Arduino's ground by checking that there is an adequate copper connection between all parts.
Similarly the Arduino is powered from the common battery. Try feeding it directly from the battery terminal via a separate wire rather than sharing a feed at any point. Is the feed to the Arduino well decoupled close to the board, say 10uF + 100nF?
Could your code or circuit be changed to cause a soft start to the power at switch on? Either by  changing the code to use analogWrite and ramp up the signal rather than a sudden jump, or add a capacitor across T4 so that the gate of T3 is slugged.

Comment: At the board, the Arduino is connected directlhy to the battey, as well as the regulator. within the board, the grounds from the Arduino and the regulator are separated. I will try using analogWrite to ramp up de signal. thank u for those tips.

Comment: @comandantexd OK, so no long and / or thin bits of wire in any of the power feeds and the PSU and the Arduino are fed as independently as possible,

Comment: Thanks for your help, doing analogWrite to ramp up the voltage, using higher capacitor for C4 (330uF) and adding a 100nF capacitor near the Arduino's power line did the trick.

Comment: I presume that you are also ramping the drive down again for exactly the same reasons.